# Can you have an operator on a vector space such that it is injective but its kernel is not the zero element?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Take any vector space $V$ and an operator $T : V \mapsto V$

Can there exist a $T$ such that it is injective but $\ker T \neq \{0\}$ and equal to some other element instead?

Comment: what have you tried?Just by definition you can prove that $T$ is injective iff $Ker($T$)$={0}

Comment: Let $V = \mathbb{R}$ and let $T = f(x) = x - 1$

Then $ \forall x \in V/\{1\}$ $f(x) \neq 0 $

Therefore, $ f(1) = 0 $ implying that $\ker T = \{1\}$

Comment: But I doubt it is correct

Comment: Is your $T$ linear?

Comment: In this case no

Comment: What do mean by operator ?If operator means linear operator then your example does not work.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake by assuming a non-linear operator, my bad!

Comment: Affine transformations can have different zero-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T:V\to V$ is injective, then by definition, for all $v,w \in V$, $$T(v)=T(w)\implies v=w.$$

The kernel of $T$ is defined as $$ker(T)=\{v\in V:T(v)=0\}.$$

Since $T$ is linear, we have that $T(0)=0$. It then follows from the injectivity of $T$ that for all $v\in V$, $$T(v)=T(0)=0 \implies v=0.$$

So, clearly $ker(T)=\{0\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Not if the operator is linear. Linearity means it must send zero to zero. From there, injectivity would tell us that it can send *only* zero to zero.

If an operator can really just be any old function, then "kernel" is a pretty meaningless notion. I'm also not aware of people calling nonlinear functions "operators" (but that doesn't mean they don't).